# How to run a python script with arguments?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, terminal, compiler-flags

I downloaded some code from the web which is a python script. When i run it with my IDE this is the output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/user/PycharmProjects/Pruebas/RBM.py
usage: RBM.py [-h] -d DATASET -t TEST [-s SEARCH]
RBM.py: error: argument -d/--dataset is required
```

The script has some data in format of a .CSV file with the code, i guess i need to run it in the terminal with some parameters, how can i do this in python?, this is what I had tried:

```
invci-4-244:~ user$ ls
Desktop         Libros          PycharmProjects
Documents       Movies          Torrents
Downloads       Music           Untitled.py
Dropbox         NetBeansProjects    nltk_data
GitHub          Pictures        pycharm-themes
Library         Public          scikit_learn_data
invci-4-244:~ user$ cd pycharm-themes/
invci-4-244:pycharm-themes user$ cd
invci-4-244:~ user$ ls
Desktop         Libros          PycharmProjects
Documents       Movies          Torrents
Downloads       Music           Untitled.py
Dropbox         NetBeansProjects    nltk_data
GitHub          Pictures        pycharm-themes
Library         Public          scikit_learn_data
invci-4-244:~ user$ cd PycharmProjects/
invci-4-244:PycharmProjects user$ ls
Pruebas
invci-4-244:PycharmProjects user$ cd Pruebas/
invci-4-244:Pruebas user$ ls
01_start.py             PruebasVectorizacion.py
02_tuning.py                RBM.py
invci-4-244:Pruebas user$ python ./RBM.py -d//Users/user/Desktop/rbm-logit-mnist/data/digits.csv
```

The name of the script is RBM.py and the data name is digits.csv, how can i solve this?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the usage output I think the syntax should be (note the space between -d and the csv path):

```
python ./RBM.py -d /Users/user/Desktop/rbm-logit-mnist/data/digits.csv
```

Comment: again: `invci-4-244:Pruebas user$ python ./RBM.py -d /Users/user/Desktop/rbm-logit-mnist/data/digits.csv
usage: RBM.py [-h] -d DATASET -t TEST [-s SEARCH]
RBM.py: error: argument -t/--test is required`

Comment: ´RBM.py [-h] -d DATASET -t TEST [-s SEARCH]
RBM.py: error: argument -t/--test: expected one argument´

Comment: It's complaining that you need to provide a -t TEST argument.  What it's expecting for TEST I don't know, you could try getting help from the script author or other examples floating around the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script from the terminal, you can type`python script.py arguments`